# Пересоздание фрагментов

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-viewpager

Почему при переходе по табам, фрагменты пересоздаются? Вот мой код:

```
public class TabFragmentU extends Fragment {
    ViewPager pager;
    PagerTabStrip tab_strp;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        setRetainInstance(true);
            View x =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_tab, null);

        tab_strp=(PagerTabStrip)x.findViewById(R.id.tab_strip);
        tab_strp.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tab_strp.setTabIndicatorColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
        tab_strp.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255,88,6));

        ma_pager_adapter adapter=new ma_pager_adapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        pager=(ViewPager)x.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        return x;
    }

    public class ma_pager_adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public ma_pager_adapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    AllOrdersFragment  t1 = new AllOrdersFragment();;
                    return t1;
                case 1:
                    ListNewsFragmentLocal t2 = new ListNewsFragmentLocal();
                    return t2;
                case 2:
                    ListBisinessFragmentLocal t3 = new ListBisinessFragmentLocal();
                    return t3;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }//set the number of tabs

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
                case 0 :
                    return "Заявки";
                case 1 :
                    return "Новости";
                case 2 :
                    return "Бизнес";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Будьте добры форматировать код перед публикацией вопроса.

Comment: Также соблюдайте конвенции именования - без нижних подчёркиваний в имени класса и с большой буквы

Comment: По собственно вопросу - фрагмент во фрагменте - плохая идея в принципе. Попробуйте сменить класс адаптера на FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Comment: "фрагмент во фрагменте - плохая идея в принципе"  можете  по детальнее объяснить,какие есть другие варианты?

Comment: Этой ситуации можно избежать, если сменить фрагмент на активити и уже в неё запихнуть ViewPager

Comment: спасибо понел  вас

Comment: сделал как вы написали,в отдельном  активити,но все равно пересоздается

Comment: Вообще пересоздаваться не должны. Но, может быть, вам надо увеличить кол-во сохраняемых фрагментов слева,справа от текущего. setOffscreenPageLimit. А может, дело вообще во фрагментах внутри pager-a попробуйте пустые фрагменты туда поставить и отследить какие методы их жизненного цикла вызываются. Может у вас они не пересоздаются, а лишь данные в них почему-то переназначаются

Comment: у меня во фрагментах используются recylerview  для вывода json ,просто когда я перелистываю мой pager,данные в recylerview дублируются

Comment: Значит проблема у вас в логике получения/добавляения/отображения данных в списке

Comment: слушайте  я заметил следующее:  если я подключаю через  адаптер 2 фрагмента то все норм  ,а  если 3 то при переходе на  третий пересоздается 1 фрагмент

Comment: Это из-за дефолтной настройки пейджера. Поставьте ему setOffscreenPageLimit(2)

Comment: спасибо вам огромное,проблема решена!

Comment: можете свой вк скинуть?

Comment: Ваша проблема не решена - вы лишь скрыли её на время. Если вы пересоздадите активити, то данные всё одно дублируются, т.к. фрагменты будут пересозданы. Т.е. вам надо искать ошибку в логике работы с данными во фрагментах. А вк вам мой зачем?.. 0_о

Comment: вы про  onsaveinstancestate? я ищу наставника по андроид разработке,разумеется буду оплачивать по возможности

Comment: И про него в том числе. На наставничество у меня, к сожалению, нет ни минуты времени

Comment: хорошо спасибо.